# If statement to confirm the numbers are a multiple of 3 and print them

Tags: javascript

Use a for loop to go through all numbers from number up to 50 (both inclusive), and check if they are multiples of 3. If they are, print them.

```
for(var number = 42; number <= 50; number++)


   while (number % 3 == 0 ){
       console.log(number);
       break;
   }
```

I don't know what my if statement should be.

Comment: You dont need while loop inside a for loop

Comment: Use an “if” statement instead?

Comment: do it like `let devidedbyThree = [];

for(var number =42; number <=50; number ++){
 if(number %3 == 0){
  devidedbyThree.push(number)
 }
}

console.log(devidedbyThree)` this

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var number = 0; number <= 50; number++)
    if (number % 3 == 0 ){
       console.log(number);
   }
```

a while-loop is not the way you are looking for.
use an if-statement and remove the `break` to continue iterating the for loop